# How to check if given variable exist in jinja2 template?

Tags: python, jinja2

Let's say, I created a template object (f.e. using `environment.from_string(template_path)`). Is it possible to check whether given variable name exist in created template?

I would like to know, if

```
template.render(x="text for x")
```

would have any effect (if something would be actually replaced by "text for x" or not). How to check if variable x exist?

Comment: Do you want to check for the variable before you render the template or in the template?

Comment: Before rendering! I need to check whether the rendering effect would make any sense...

Comment: So you want to check that the variable x is actually referenced in the template?

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

From the documentation:

**defined(value)**

Return true if the variable is defined:

```
{% if variable is defined %}
    value of variable: {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
See the default() filter for a simple way to set undefined variables.
```

EDIT:
It seems you want to know if a value passed in to the rendering context. In that case you can use [jinja2.meta.find_undeclared_variables](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#jinja2.meta.find_undeclared_variables), which will return you a list of all variables used in the templates to be evaluated.

Comment: Not exactly what I meant - I need to check whether the `{{ variable }}` fragment exists in template text or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, or if it will work in all cases, but I'll assume you have the template text in a string, either because you've created it with a string or your program has read the source template into a string.

I would use the regular expression library, re

```
>>> import re
>>> template = "{% block body %} This is x.foo: {{ x.foo }} {% endblock %}"
>>> expr = "\{\{.*x.*\}\}"
>>> result = re.search(expr, template)
>>> try: 
>>>     print result.group(0)
>>> except IndexError:
>>>     print "Variable not used"
```

The result will be:

```
'{{ x.foo }}'
```

or throw the exception I caught:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
```

which will print "Variable not used"

Answer (score -4):

You can't do that.

I suppose you could parse the template and then walk the AST to see if there are references, but that would be somewhat complicated code.

Comment: You brought bad news for me. Could you please provide any suggestions for such parsing? Jinja2 probably parse it anyway, I wonder whether it is possible to gain access to effects of this process.